# How to install two activities as one application in Xamarin Android C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin Android C# development and still reading tutorials ..
And I'm having a hard time merging two activities in one application .. Though I followed all the instructions in the tutorial I wonder why this happen .. I hope someone could somehow help me with this ..

I have 2 activities: *"FirstActivity"* and *"SecondActity"*

[image]

What I desired was to install this as one Application,
but the output was like this:

[image]

2 *"Android Two"* applications ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have the `MainLauncher` attribute set to true on both of `ActivityOne` and `ActivityTwo`.

EG:

```
[Activity (Label = "Activity One", MainLauncher = true)]
public class ActivityOne : Activity
{
    // ...
}
```

And...

```
[Activity (Label = "Activity Two", MainLauncher = true)]
public class ActivityTwo : Activity
{
    // ...
}
```

Remove the `MainLauncher = true` attribute from one of those activities and your application will then only have one launcher.

See [this documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml) under the section titled "Launchable from Application Chooser".